# Suggestions to web based low-security password alternative

Tags: passwords

I have an corporate intranet project that needs logins, but doesn't need high security.  Impersonating a different user is not useful or very desirable.  In similar intranet systems, everyone has the same password as setup by the admin.

I'm hoping to get some suggestions on what password alternatives I could consider.  My first thought is to show each user 8 images and have them click on one to be their password.  Would this be too annoying or problematic in someway?  What other ideas would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a text based password? It sounds like you are over-complicating things by including images, especially if, as you stated, don't need "high security". I wouldn't consider a text based password "high security" but it does meet your requirements of a login on the intranet. A lot of products have built in functions for passwords so it would be dead simple to implement into your project if you have this available. I'm suggesting you keep it simple and don't assume that impersonating a user isn't something that won't happen without at least a password. You'd want to know who made changes or have some logs that identified who was the user at the time of a certain event.

Remember, security should be baked in, not sprayed on!